# Selenium scraping website has load more button, dynamic loading data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web

I trying to scrape all product from this website https://cellphones.com.vn/catalogsearch/result?q=tivi
but i can't figure out how to click the 'load more' button.

I tried using

```
while (True):
  try:
    button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='load-more-btn']").click()
    time.sleep(1)
  except:
    break
```

but it didn't work. I check the network tab but it didn't help because i can't find the size of the page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
while True:
   try:
      button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='load-more-btn']").click()
      break
   except:
      time.sleep(1)
      pass
```

and maybe add a counter limit of like 10 tries